# ‏costs of Firebase read and Google Analytics

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I didn't understand the value of Firebase Firestore costs, but let's say a fixed number and the read count is also fixed at 1 million reads each day.  Does that mean in a pay-as-you-go plan the cost is around $1.2 per day?  I didn't understand everything on the Firebase site so I'm afraid of high bills so tell me if there's something to pay attention to, I use read-only and data analysis from Google Is everything safe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple factors related to Firestore pricing and it varies by your Firestore region as well. Assuming your location is US, then you'll be charged `$0.06 per 100,000 documents` so if you have a million reads a day then it'll cost `$0.6` per day for the *read operations*.

You are also charged for the amount of data stored in the database (1 GB / month is free) and `$0.18 / GiB / month` thereafter. So if you have 10 GB of data stored for a month, that'll be another `$1.62` a month.

If you are serving data across multiple regions, then you'll get some network charges that are listed in the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/firestore/pricing).